# Unable to connect to mysql remote

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-cluster, remote

I am struggling to connect MySQL database with my application, I am having the following set up

1. 3 Applications running in cluster mode and trying to connect with same DB.
2. MySQL database running on cluster mode ( Active / Passive)

I am able to connect to MySQL from the database server itself but when I am trying to connect with DB server from my application, I am getting `Access denied`.

Here are few additional details

```
+--------------------------------+
| UserAccount                    |
+--------------------------------+
| 'myuser'@'%'           |       |
| 'root'@'127.0.0.1'             |
| 'root'@'::1'                   |
|                                |
| 'myuser'@'localhost'   |       |
| 'root'@'localhost'             |
+--------------------------------+
```

MySQl service is up and running to listening to a specific IP

```
netstat -nap | grep mysql

tcp        0      0 serverIP:3306           0.0.0.0:*                  LISTEN      723/mysqld 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     603869 723/mysqld          /mysql/mysql.sock
```

For me things are looking good, even telnet to server IP with port 3306 shows me success.

but when I am trying to connect with MySQL from my application or from my local terminal , it is giving me exception

```
> mysql -u myuser -p db -h remoteIP --skip-secure-auth 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'remoteIP' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone help me to understand as where the things are incorrect,

Comment: Did you run a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after adding the `'myuser'@'%'` grant?

Comment: it seems some password related issue..Can you set password to some simple one and then try..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the host information as the first item in your connection string

> mysql -hremoteIP -umyuser -p db